# why applicationName is primary key instead of application-Id in asp.net applications table?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, asp.net-membership, relational-database, asp.net-4.0

I have a question about aspnet_applications table I have created asp.net membership using .net framework 4.0 it created some tables but I don't understand why Microsoft generate aspnet_applications table like this :

ApplicationName            -> **Primary key** 
LoweredApplicationName   
ApplicationId              -> **unique index**
Description

I think about this in my opinion applicationId should be a key and application name should be an unique index but Microsoft have done completely conversely. and I have some trouble in .net entity model when I need updating model from database it couldn't updated. I mean it couldn't make associations.

What is the main reason defining Application-Name as primary key instead of application-Id?

Comment: Strange, my own ASPNET database (created with VS2008) does have `ApplicationId` as the primary key. Documentation [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478948.aspx) [the same](http://www.adivo.com/samples/database/aspnetdb/ASPNETDB.html#TB-ASPNETDB-aspnet_Applications). It might be specific to .NET 4, but I couldn't find anything mentioning that change.

Comment: yes I have been using .net framework 4.0 and generator tools to create database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no difference. A primary key constraint and a unique constraint on non-nullable columns means exactly the same thing and they work just the same way.

In principle, all keys are equal and which one you designate to be the "primary" one is mostly a matter of style and readability.

Comment: I don't agree with readability because all of relations are based on ApplicationId, I think your answer was correct if relation would be on ApplicationName not applicationId.

Comment: By "relation" I guess you mean "foreign key". A foreign key can reference any key (in fact any unique constraint or index) not just the primary key. You are right that by convention foreign keys reference the "primary" key - that's not universally the case however and isn't necessarily a wise assumption.